# Bootstrap: move navbar under the logo bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> Is it possible to move the navbar under the first top bar so i have the bar with the logo first and then the navigation?

Comment: Remove the bootstrap `.navbar-fixed-top` and then you are on the right way! Or do you want the navbar fixed when scrolling?

Comment: @djl Yep i need it fixed :/

Comment: Can you use JQuery? Then I know a solution:)

Comment: @djl Yeah i can try... im not skilled but ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery:

**HTML**
Give your navbar an ID, in my example `<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">`

**JQUERY**

```
var logoBarHeight = $('.logo-bar').height();

$(document).on('scroll', function() { 
  if($(document).scrollTop() > logoBarHeight){
    $('#navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  } else {
    $('#navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  }
});
```

Comment: should i place the JQUERY before the <body>" section ends?

Like <script> *Your JQUERY Code</script>
Cause i tried but does not works...

Comment: Yes inside `<script></script>` at the bottom of the code. Or in a .js file if you are using that. (Note, I edited the code a little bit..)

Comment: It works on Desktop Mode but could be possible that the JQUERY blocks the "navigation" on mobile? When you try to go responsive and click on the Toggle menu links does not appears...

Comment: Don't use fixed navigationbars on mobile.. I CSS overwrite the position fixed of bootstrap on small screens.

Comment: Good, thanks for the suggestion. It's a big thing for you to tell me how can i overwrite it on small screen? I know that i have to use media queries...

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { .navbar-fixed-top { position:relative; } }` 480px can you adjust the way you like:)

Answer (score 0):

try this by adding to your css

```
#navbar{ margin-top: 106px;}

 .container-fluid.logo-bar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

and change this image styles

```
<img src="http://yr-neu.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/img/bg_3.png" class="special" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i think the JQUERY solution fit my situation :)